# $x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x + 2\cos x = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

> $x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x + 2\cos x = 0$

How do I find the number of solutions of  this equation (in $[0, 2\pi]$) **without** a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ybqq34hbch)?

Attempt:

The equation simplifies to $x(x^2 + 2x + 5)=- 2\cos x $

Minima of the quadratic occurs at $x= -1$ and it's value is $4$

Minima of $-2\cos x$ is $-2$

Answer (score 4):

> Let $$f(x)=x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x + 2\cos x$$

Then $$f'(x)=3x^2+4x-2\sin x+5$$  Since $$3x^2+4x+5>2\ge 2\sin x$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $$f'(x)>0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus $f$ is monotonically increasing for all real $x$.

Now as $$f(-1)=-1+2-5+1.08...=-2.91...<0,$$ $$f(0)=0+0+0+2=2>0$$ and $f$ is continuous for all values of $x$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem the equation $$f(x)=0$$ has only one solution.

**P.S.** If you are interested, the value of $x$ such that $f$ crosses the $x$-axis is around $-0.421$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2vnhsxqgz2

Answer (score 3):

Look first at the cubic part. You see that it is always increasing, and the minimum derivative is found at the inflection point, which is at $x=-2/3$. The derivative there has value $11/3>2$,  so that the whole function, including the trigonometric part, is increasing. Thus it has only one root.

Answer (score 2):

**You *will have to* sketch a graph to find the number of solutions.**

You don't need to get it exactly detailed and in the right scale, so you can do it on rough paper pretty easily without a calculator.

**But how?**

You identified the first part correctly, separating the two different functions from each other:

$$x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x=- 2\cos x $$
Now, sketching the RHS on rough paper is very easy. We'll focus on the polynomial in the LHS.

Turning point of the cubic occurs at $3x^2+4x+5=0$ which has zero solutions ($\because D<0$), hence, there is no turning point i.e. the function $f(x)$ is monotonic. The coefficient of $x^3$ is $>1$, which implies the cubic starts from $-\infty$ when $x\rightarrow-\infty$, crosses the y-axis at $(0,5)$ and goes till $+\infty$ when $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Now, $f(-1)=-1+2-5=-4<-2$ and $f(x)$ $\forall x<-1$ is less than $-2$. Hence, **notice $f(x)$ has intersected $y=-\cos x$ in interval (0,1)** .

Knowing the nature of LHS and RHS, we can easily comment that there will not be any more points of intersection.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

$$y_1=-x^3-5x$$ and $$y_2=2x^2+2\cos x$$

for $x\ge0,  y_1<0, y_2>0$

for $-1<x<0$ both function decrease and have only one intersection

for $x\le-1$ there are no intersection $$-x^3-5x<2x^2+2\cos x$$